# Map matching: Large missing gap between GPS points leads to straight line

Tags: map-matching, valhalla

**GeoJSON Data:**

```
{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[151.07629,-33.85464],[151.07555,-33.85493],[151.07479,-33.85514],[151.07385,-33.85545],[151.07295,-33.8558],[151.07207,-33.85612],[151.07125,-33.85657],[151.07099,-33.85674],[151.071,-33.85674],[151.07092,-33.85679],[151.07066,-33.85698],[151.0705,-33.85711],[151.07009,-33.85756],[151.06962,-33.85821],[151.06914,-33.85902],[151.06859,-33.85995],[151.06804,-33.86085],[151.06749,-33.86172],[151.06693,-33.86265],[151.0665,-33.86365],[151.06622,-33.86449],[151.06587,-33.86536],[151.06548,-33.86621],[151.06495,-33.86695],[151.0645,-33.86775],[151.06408,-33.86862],[151.06409,-33.86956],[151.06463,-33.87052],[151.0654,-33.87147],[151.06603,-33.87247],[151.06653,-33.87339],[151.06692,-33.87428],[151.06724,-33.87528],[151.06756,-33.87629],[151.06784,-33.87736],[151.06816,-33.87845],[151.06852,-33.87953],[151.06882,-33.88047],[151.06916,-33.88148],[151.06938,-33.88248],[151.06952,-33.88346],[151.0697,-33.88452],[151.06941,-33.8855],[151.06865,-33.88628],[151.06791,-33.88698],[151.0675,-33.8879],[151.06741,-33.88893],[151.06727,-33.88997],[151.06712,-33.89088],[151.06692,-33.89184],[151.06669,-33.89283],[151.06654,-33.89383],[151.06642,-33.89484],[151.06621,-33.89575],[151.06601,-33.89666],[151.06588,-33.89769],[151.06562,-33.89872],[151.06537,-33.89973],[151.06513,-33.90071],[151.06494,-33.9017],[151.06476,-33.90257],[151.0646,-33.90291],[151.0646,-33.9029],[151.0646,-33.90291],[151.06459,-33.90298],[151.06461,-33.90324],[151.06447,-33.90411],[151.06424,-33.90511],[151.06408,-33.90615],[151.06426,-33.90684],[151.06449,-33.90701],[151.06448,-33.90704],[151.06445,-33.90713],[151.06444,-33.90756],[151.06441,-33.90836],[151.06419,-33.90935],[151.06394,-33.91031],[151.06375,-33.91127],[151.06351,-33.91217],[151.06332,-33.91306],[151.06309,-33.91407],[151.06292,-33.91499],[151.06295,-33.91574],[151.06312,-33.91596],[151.06309,-33.91593],[151.06306,-33.9159],[151.06305,-33.91589],[151.0631,-33.91592],[151.0634,-33.91616],[151.06398,-33.91656],[151.06455,-33.917],[151.06514,-33.91747],[151.06569,-33.91801],[151.06594,-33.91842],[151.06622,-33.91891],[151.06654,-33.91947],[151.06684,-33.92006],[151.06715,-33.9206],[151.06753,-33.92122],[151.06793,-33.92183],[151.06824,-33.92244],[151.06869,-33.92319],[151.06924,-33.92392],[151.06967,-33.92476],[151.07009,-33.92556],[151.07052,-33.92632],[151.07097,-33.92706],[151.07126,-33.92761],[151.07138,-33.9278],[151.07152,-33.928],[151.07151,-33.92799],[151.07152,-33.928],[151.07153,-33.92802],[151.07153,-33.92803],[151.07158,-33.92814],[151.07187,-33.92862],[151.07226,-33.92925],[151.07261,-33.92999],[151.07288,-33.93065],[151.07295,-33.93127],[151.07302,-33.93196],[151.07318,-33.93265],[151.07335,-33.93337],[151.07351,-33.93413],[151.07375,-33.93486],[151.07407,-33.93563],[151.07435,-33.93648],[151.07465,-33.93727],[151.07499,-33.93799],[151.07524,-33.9387],[151.07554,-33.9394],[151.07583,-33.94013],[151.07609,-33.94076],[151.07634,-33.94147],[151.0764,-33.94167],[151.07638,-33.94162],[151.07639,-33.94166],[151.07667,-33.94217],[151.07711,-33.94275],[151.07725,-33.94292],[151.07724,-33.9429],[151.07774,-33.9429],[151.07902,-33.9425],[151.08027,-33.94193],[151.08147,-33.94146],[151.08261,-33.94104],[151.08378,-33.94054],[151.08499,-33.93999],[151.08628,-33.93983],[151.08762,-33.93975],[151.0889,-33.93985],[151.09024,-33.93995],[151.09143,-33.94007],[151.09254,-33.94013],[151.09377,-33.94005],[151.09506,-33.93997],[151.09646,-33.93977],[151.09779,-33.93949],[151.09907,-33.93908],[151.10027,-33.93861],[151.10148,-33.9382],[151.10256,-33.93763],[151.1038,-33.93705],[151.10492,-33.93667],[151.10622,-33.93644],[151.1075,-33.93627],[151.10883,-33.93612],[151.11025,-33.93605],[151.11154,-33.93601],[151.11294,-33.93581],[151.11433,-33.9356],[151.1148,-33.93553],[151.11705,-33.93519],[151.11743,-33.93513],[151.11715,-33.93517],[151.11658,-33.93526],[151.10774,-33.93668],[151.15434,-33.94123],[151.15871,-33.94139],[151.15434,-33.94123],[151.14944,-33.93809],[151.15416,-33.93652],[151.15459,-33.93653],[151.15539,-33.93601],[151.15622,-33.93551],[151.15706,-33.93499],[151.15803,-33.93454],[151.15902,-33.93423],[151.16005,-33.93405],[151.161,-33.93389],[151.16191,-33.93366],[151.16262,-33.9333],[151.16299,-33.93255],[151.16329,-33.93176],[151.16379,-33.93102],[151.16444,-33.93042],[151.16502,-33.92984],[151.16568,-33.92934],[151.16648,-33.92888],[151.16732,-33.92841],[151.16816,-33.92789],[151.16894,-33.92742],[151.16988,-33.92722],[151.17076,-33.92705],[151.17144,-33.9269],[151.17163,-33.92686],[151.17189,-33.92678],[151.1727,-33.92668],[151.17349,-33.92653],[151.17442,-33.92646],[151.17539,-33.92643],[151.17635,-33.92623],[151.17736,-33.92601],[151.1784,-33.92579],[151.17947,-33.92574],[151.18047,-33.92603],[151.18141,-33.92627],[151.18235,-33.92651],[151.18323,-33.92693],[151.18381,-33.92764],[151.18399,-33.92846],[151.18388,-33.9292],[151.18376,-33.92976],[151.18371,-33.9304],[151.18406,-33.93112],[151.18479,-33.9316],[151.18546,-33.93191],[151.1859,-33.93208],[151.18592,-33.93207],[151.18591,-33.93207],[151.18593,-33.93207],[151.18614,-33.93226],[151.18619,-33.93286],[151.18605,-33.93351],[151.18557,-33.93406],[151.18487,-33.93424],[151.18412,-33.9343],[151.18345,-33.93424],[151.18278,-33.9341],[151.18216,-33.93389],[151.18156,-33.93386],[151.18099,-33.93391],[151.18053,-33.93388],[151.18032,-33.93385],[151.17992,-33.93399],[151.17996,-33.93404],[151.17998,-33.93407],[151.17996,-33.93406],[151.18007,-33.93406],[151.18002,-33.93407],[151.18,-33.93409],[151.18001,-33.93407],[151.18,-33.93406],[151.18006,-33.93409],[151.18004,-33.93406],[151.17996,-33.93408],[151.17992,-33.93404],[151.17981,-33.93397],[151.17922,-33.93388],[151.17888,-33.93376],[151.17887,-33.93375],[151.17876,-33.93369],[151.17858,-33.9328],[151.17875,-33.93259],[151.17881,-33.93256],[151.17897,-33.93244],[151.17886,-33.93271],[151.17891,-33.93268],[151.1789,-33.93271],[151.1789,-33.93272],[151.17889,-33.93272],[151.17888,-33.93264],[151.17887,-33.93263],[151.17898,-33.93265],[151.17913,-33.93271],[151.17943,-33.93277],[151.18021,-33.93256]]}
```

**Raw GPS Data on Map**

[image]

**Testing URL:**

This is Valhalla's Map Matching Demo

https://valhalla.github.io/demos/map_matching/#loc=13,-33.918506,151.101494&costing=%22auto%22

**Map Matched Result:**

[image]

**Issue Summary:**

Due to there being a tunnel along the path, there's a large gap between the GPS point at the start and end of the tunnel. Valhalla does not create a map-matched path between the two points.

How can I have it so there's a path along the tunnel?

I have Valhalla deployed on my server and can modify the config such as `search_radius` and `max_search_radius` - I've tested it to around `1000` for `max_search radius` and I'm passing `accuracy` with each gps point within `shape` to Valhalla's `trace_attributes` API.